# Consecutive primitive roots of congruence $x^n\equiv \bmod (m) $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consecutive primitive roots of congruence $x^n\equiv \mod (m) $

I saw in this site that: There is no algorithm for finding primitive roots of congruence $x^n\equiv \mod (m) $. Here I discuss a certain case:

Consider following identity:

$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+b^{n-1})$

suppose a and b are two consecutive numbers and $a=b+1$  we have:

$(b+1)^n-b^n=(1)[(b+1)^{n-1}+(b+1)^{n-2}b+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+b^{n-1}]$

Let $(b+1)^{n-1}+(b+1)^{n-2}b+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+b^{n-1}=m$

suppose $b+1$ and $b$ have a remainder $r$ when divided by m i.e we can write:

$(b+1)^n \equiv r \mod(m)$

$b\equiv r \mod (m)$

Subtracting these relations gives:

$(b+1)^n-b^n \equiv 0 \mod(m)$

rewriting this as:

$(b+1)^n\equiv b^n\equiv r \mod(m)$

For example :

$5^2\equiv 3 \mod (11)$

$6^2\equiv 3 \mod (11)$

5 and 6 are consecutive roots of congruence $x^2\equiv 3 \mod (11)$

Hence we can conclude  that any number of the form $(b+1)^n-b^n=(b+1)^{n-1}+(b+1)^{n-2}b+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+b^{n-1}=m$ has two consecutive roots in congruence $x^n\equiv r \mod(m)$ and these roots may be primitive for certain value of r which can be found by following relation:

$b^n \equiv r \mod(m)$

Clearly b can have any value, so the number of these types of congruence can be infinite.

My question is : can this method be correct for large m, in other words can b and b+1 always two of  primitive roots? can someone give a counter example?

Update:I checked number$13^3-12^3=469$:

$12^3\equiv 321\bmod{469}$

$13^3\equiv 321\bmod{469}$

I found some more solutions; 80, 146, 213, 243, 348 for remainder 321 but none of them are primitive.I do not think these type of number have primitive roots for any n.

Comment: `\pmod{m}` produces a parenthetical $(\mathrm{mod}\ m)$ with appropriate spacing. Don’t use `\mod` in any case, which has the wrong spacing; for the binary mod operator, use `\bmod`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is a way of finding two consecutive integers which have the same $n$th power for some modulus.

However, this is not what 'primitive root' means. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n

In your own example, $5^5\equiv 1\pmod {11}$ and so $5$ is **not** a primitive root modulo $11$.